# Using ForgeJS in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I've read about using external javascript posts here, yet i am confused. Is ForgeJS can be used in lightning components/app?. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForceJS does not run because of an error that surfaces in THREE, which brings WebGL to the masses in an easy-to-use manner. The culprit appears to be WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D not working correctly. The precise error suggests that Locker Service is missing this method, resulting in a broken display. It gets as far as initializing WebGL, but loading the textures causes an error that cascades through the rest of the code, ultimately ending up with just a black area where the VR/3D experience would be. You might try submitting a bug in regards to this, since WebGL is supposedly supported in Lightning. The precise error looks like this:

```
THREE.WebGLState: TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at Proxy.b (aura_prod.js:24)
    at Object.texImage2D (three:139)
    at dg.r [as setTexture2D] (three:115)
    at Xd.eval [as setTexture2D] (three:200)
    at Ff.rf [as setValue] (three:20)
    at Function.eb.upload (three:363)
    at p (three:166)
    at Xd.renderBufferDirect (three:190)
    at q (three:154)
    at m (three:154)
```

(NOTE: This is the minified version, you might consider running the full version to get better feedback).

Note that this probably means that nothing WebGL-related works in Lightning right now, but you might be able to work out a way to do this with SVG or a Canvas if you took the time, but you'll have to build your own or find a setup that doesn't use WebGL.

---

Here's the code that I used:

```
<aura:application >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.three,$Resource.hammer,$Resource.forge)}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.activate}" />
    <div id="container"></div>
</aura:application>
```

---

```
.THIS#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

```
({
    activate: function(component, event, helper) {
        var config = {
            "story":
            {
                "uid": "simpliest-story",
                "name": "Simpliest Story",
                "slug": "simpliest-story",
                "description": "This is the simpliest story ever",
                "default": "scene-0",

                "scenes":
                [
                    {
                        "uid": "scene-0",
                        "name": "First scene",
                        "slug": "first-scene",
                        "description": "This is the first and only scene",

                        "media":
                        {
                            "uid": "media-0",
                            "type": "image",

                            "source":
                            {
                                "format": "equi",
                                "url": "https://<redacted>-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/forest"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        };

        // Create a viewer
        var viewer = new FORGE.Viewer("container", config);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer sfdcfox. With this, I cannot push through developing our lightning component which is some sort of a virtual tour. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @JayveeVillaceran You probably *can*, but not via this library. Try doing some more research.

Comment: @sfdcdox I found some but only in implementing via iframe, we are actually finding solutions similar to this that is natively coded inside the component. 

We tried Matterport SDK and Panotours also.